# How to build a new OS on top of a Linux OS

Tags: linux

I'd like to build my own operating system (really just the Ubuntu distro as I know the task is difficult) But what I mean by this is I wish to build atop of the Ubuntu operating system as like Apple has done with OS X building it atop of UNIX. I would like to do the same thing with a distribution of Ubuntu Linux except my business would be in control of everything, instead of Canonical Ltd.

This question is different from just an Ubuntu Live CD because I don't want to create an almost entirely different OS then Ubuntu. In fact that is why I say that "I'd like to build my own operating system".

Comment: you can refer this link http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: If you want to do that your base has to be Debian - not Ubuntu (like Ubuntu has built up from Debian).

Comment: @Nils why? there's no reason to base on Debian instead of Ubuntu (the main Mint edition is based on Ubuntu). edit: i mean there's no mandating reason. you can use either.

Comment: @strugee Debian Mint and Ubuntu are both based on Debian-Testing. But I would not say that Mint is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nils nope, Mint is mostly based on Ubuntu. they do have a version called Mint Debian Edition, though, that's based on Debian.

Comment: Start from some ready to use cross toolchain for embedded system: see BuildRoot or OpenWrt, and build it for your i386 target system and Raspberry Pi. It now includes huge set of libs (Qt embedded,..), GUI system, Python,... So you will get tiny system, unlinked from your working host-OS

Comment: You asked Ububntu, but this buildroot have large community too

Answer (score 4):

Your question is quite inconsistent. You want to build a completely different system, but almost equal to Ubuntu. And to boot you want to build a whole business separate from Canonical, completely controlling this. Please make up your mind, and break up your question into individually answerable pieces.

Also check on the licenses under which the pieces of Ubuntu (and the other Linx distributions) are to be used. You will see that complete control, like Apple has, is completely out of the question for such a system. And consider Apple did pour *vast* resources into creating the system they currently distribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `remastersys` application for do it.

Of course,You can see list of remastering application in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_remastering_software)